# Multiplication with Java, JavaScript, Oracle and Windows Calculator

Tags: java, javascript, windows, oracle

Javascript code:

```
var unitPrice,shippintObj;
var temp2=parseFloat(unitPrice * shippingObj.value);
document.getElementById("pAmountId"+shippingId).value =temp2.toFixed(3) ;
```

output:-

```
563361462829470100000
```

Java Code:

```
    double b;
long a;
a=456322789;
b=1234567890120.145;
System.out.println(a*b);
DecimalFormat ft=new DecimalFormat("#############################.###");
String  c=ft.format(a*b);
System.out.println(c);
```

output :-

```
   5.633614628294701E20
   563361462829470100000
```

Oracle (SQL):

```
  select 
   to_char(456322789*1234567890120.145,'999999999999999999999999999999999D999')
  from dual;
```

output:-

```
  563361462829470111484.4050
```

Window Calculator:

```
    a=456322789;
    b=1234567890120.145;
```

result:-

```
    563361462829470111484.4050
```

Finally my problem is when I am doing a calculation with Java, Javascript, SQL and Windows calculator, my result is same for Java, Javascript
but it differs from answer of SQL, Windows calculator. I want to get the result of Oracle in Java and in Javascript too.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to get a result too big to fit into a `double` with required precision. Use [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class in Java to get arbitrary precision, but I'm afraid you'll have to implement long arithmetics yourself in JavaScript (unless you find a good library you can use.)

Comment: StackOverflow encourages accepting answers if they solve your issue or upvoting them if they help you in other ways.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a floating point arithmetic problem to me - consider using `BigDecimal` rather than double in your java code.

Comment: thats fine thank you for your guidance.but what i have to do with

Comment: javascript code because i have shown them button so i must get the same result in javascript too.